# Squirrel access to Phoenix/HBase

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hbase, squirrel-sql, apache-phoenix

I got phoenix 4.0 running on hbase 0.98/hadoop 2.3.0 and was impressed by the command line tools.

In the second step I followed the description on the webpage to connect to phoenix using its bundled JDBC driver.

When I try to connect I get the Exception message (on Squirrel side)

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.awaitConnection(OpenConnectionCommand.java:132)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$100(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$2.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection.
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.executeConnect(OpenConnectionCommand.java:171)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$000(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$1.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:104)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection.
    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:309)
    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:133)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1446)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:131)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:112)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.sql.SQLDriverManager.getConnection(SQLDriverManager.java:133)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.executeConnect(OpenConnectionCommand.java:167)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:309)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.HConnectionFactory$HConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(HConnectionFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:252)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:414)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Socket Factory class not found: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.net.StandardSocketFactory not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getSocketFactoryFromProperty(NetUtils.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getDefaultSocketFactory(NetUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.<init>(RpcClient.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:664)
    ... 20 more
```

I double checked the jar files with classfinder to be sure that the class org.apache.hadoop.net.StandardSocketFactory IS in the classpath.

What can I do to get Squirrel connected with Phoenix?

Update:

I saw in the zookeeper log on the server side that the network communication started:

```
2014-05-28 06:24:29,411 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /192.168.1.106:58172
2014-05-28 06:24:29,412 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.ZooKeeperServer: Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.1.106:58172
2014-05-28 06:24:29,518 INFO  [SyncThread:0] server.ZooKeeperServer: Established session 0x146413f6c3a000c with negotiated timeout 90000 for client /192.168.1.106:58172
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem replacing the downloaded binary version 4.0 of phoenix with the snapshot version 4.1 which I built by myown from the source version cloned via git from

http://git.apache.org/incubator-phoenix.git/

After the successful build I extracted the tarball from the assembly subdirectory and copied the following jars to hbase 0.98's lib dir

```
phoenix-core-4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar 
phoenix-flume-4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar
phoenix-pig-4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

In Squirrel I used just phoenix-4.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT-client.jar as a extra path to get the driver running.

Comment: Thanks it worked as well for DbVisualizer after I packaged the entire project from the source (https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/phoenix.git) and create a new jdbc driver from DbVis using the client jar (phoenix-5.0.0-SNAPSHOT-client.jar). It's not the only thing to do though if you need to get it work with this tool. Ping me if you want some help.